# The name 'Installers' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

I'm a total noob in developing windows services and I found a tutorial about implementing a standard windows service. This is the code that I found:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ReviewsSvc
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ReviewsSvcInstaller
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller;
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;

    public ReviewsSvcInstaller()
    {
        processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Reviews Updater";
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        Installers.Add(processInstaller);
    }
}
}
```

I've added the necessary references but I still get an error about 'Installers' not found. What am I missing?

Comment: What in this question is too localized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to specify the base class

```
namespace ReviewsSvc 
{ 
    [RunInstaller(true)] 
    public class ReviewsSvcInstaller : Installer
    { 
        ....
```

Comment: @MattDavey - What is your point?  The author's entire problem is the class `Installer` or `Installers` cannot be found.

Comment: @Ramhound in this example `Installers` refers to the `System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Installers` property - but as Steve pointed out his class does not derive from `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` - hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: The installer should be in a different project (different executable) or together with the service? How do I use the installer?

Comment: As you can see from this [example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx), and also from your code, the class ServiceInstaller needs to know the name of the main service class and this name should be found as the ServiceName of a class derived from ServiceBase in your project. The process to install the service (a .NET Service) is through the utility InstallUtil.exe.

Comment: @Steve - that one just bit me. thank you for reminding me to "subclass Installer"!   Mucho appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the class **ReviewsSvcInstaller** in the main executable (EXE). The installer look for this class in the main entry assembly. I hope it helps.